# Laravel Mutator for append url for JSON array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a JSON field in my MySQL table column which has an JSON array with part of URLs.

```
["products/1.jpg", "products/2.jpg", "products/3.jpg"]
```

I want to get the array with appending a Base URL for each of the values of the array.

```
["www.example.com/images/products/1.jpg", "www.example.com/images/products/2.jpg", "www.example.com/images/products/3.jpg"]
```

I have tried with getAttribute() function like nelow code. But was not succeeded.

```
public function getImagesAttribute(){
  $images = json_decode($this->attributes['images']);
  $imageP = [];
  foreach ($images as $image) {
    $imageP[] = "www.example.com/images/" . $image;
  }
  return $imageP;
}
```

can you help me.

Comment: Are you casting the json column in your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `$this->images` instead of `$this->attributes['images']`.

In this case, I would use [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections) like so:

```php
public function getImagesAttribute(){
    return collect(json_decode($this->images))
        ->map(function ($image) {
            return "www.example.com/images/" . $image;
        })
        ->all();
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much